# add more accepted protocols to url/link validation

Tags: 2010, url, validation

I'm trying to add a link that starts with the protocoll "notes://" to a URL list and in a standard rich text field but only get "the url is not valid"
How can i make sharepoint 2010 understand that this link is valid?

Can i do some kind of configuration to make SP 2010 understand that this type of link is valid?
Or do i need to program a custom field type in order to make Sp accept this type of link?

Answer (score 1):

The validation SharePoint uses on that column is hard-coded.  I can think of at least two ways to achieve a similar effect:

1) Use a custom column type you define in VS

-or-

2) Use a regular text field for entering the URL.  Then use a calculated column to concatenate strings around the URL to make it a clickable link.  Then display the calculated column...

Comment: Option 2 only works if you select "Number" as resulting return type of the calculated field and only the Gods know why this is that way.